# Why this two spaces do not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\Bbb Q$ with subspace topology and $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$ with product topology. Why this two spaces are not homeomorphic?($\Bbb Q$ is the rational numbers)

Comment: Already asked and answered in Math Overflow: 

[Are the rationals homeomorphic to any power of the rationals?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/26001/26571)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476383/does-there-exist-a-continuous-bijection-mathbbq-to-mathbbq-times-mathbb/476387

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a theorem of Sierpinski that every countable metric space without isolated points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. See eg [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm). $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is a countable metric space without isolated points. Therefore these two spaces are homeomorphic.